# how to concatenate reg ex variable between two numbers in Jmeter HTTP request

Tags: jmeter

[image]

-How can we add correct value in the rquest

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue. If the ${pins} has a value, you can use it anywhere in your test plan. I tried using Dummy Sampler for your syntax `101:191:${pins}::NO:::`, it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could add PreProccesor (Beanshell, Groovy) and put something like:

```
vars.put("newParameter", String.format("101:191:%s::NO:::", vars.get("pins")));
```

And in your request parameter put *${newParameter}*.